# VirtualBox doesnt see USB devices unless host restart

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox 4.2.28, my host is OpenSUSE 13.1 32 bit, my guest is Windows 7 32 bit. I have a problem which is when I connect my USB devices (3G modem, USB pen drive, etc...), no matter how I try VirtualBox cannot recognize the devices. But if I still connect the devices and restart my host, suddenly VirtualBox can see and work with them properly, which is quite annoying. Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thanks all.

PS: I have already added my user to vboxusers group, and installed extension pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a special reason, I had to install VirtualBox 4.3 via RPM (SUSE 13.1 repos only has 4.2 version). And the issue disappears without a track, now I can connect any USB devices whenever I want.